# Как работает метод ChartView::zoomIn(rect rectangle)

Tags: qt, qt5, qml, qtquick

Хочу, чтобы увеличивалась выбранная область:

```
ChartView{
id: chart

Rectangle{
id: rect
color: "white"
visible: false
}

ScatterSeries{
// какие-тт точки 
}

MouseArea{
anchors.fill: parent
hoverEnabled: true
acceptedButtons: Qt.AllButtons

onPressed: {rect.x = mouseX; rect.y = mouseY; rect.visible = true}
onMouseXChanged: {rect.width = mouseX - rect.x}
onMouseYChanged: {rect.height = mouseY - rect.y}
onReleased: {chart.zoomIn(rect); rect.visible = false} //нет никакой реакции
}
}
```

Подскажите, как правильно использовать `ChartView::zoomIn(rect rectangle)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Помогло следующее:

```
Rectangle{
    id: rectang
    ...
}

onReleased: {
        chart.zoomIn(Qt.rect(rectang.x, rectang.y, rectang.width, rectang.height))
        rectang.visible = false
}
```

Я ошибочно полагал, что  `rect` и `Rectangle` это одинаковые типы.